# Objective C what are Frozen Objects

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

XIB files are said to contain frozen Objects. What does it mean ? What are frozen objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are really cold.

Saying an "object is frozen" is just another way to say the object is "serialized" or "flattened" or even "marshalled".

These are all terms for taking the data of an object and storing it in some type of structure (often a file) so that at a later point the exact same object can be recreated by reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

"Frozen objects": Its just a term used to say the objects(XIB) will be saved in the file system so that the same object can be again created by reading it. Usually it will be saved/archived in some standard of xml.